# When are the categories of algebras over props (co)complete?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, universal-algebra, operads, accessible-categories

Suppose P is a (colored) [prop](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/PROP) in a closed symmetric monoidal locally presentable category C. Is the category Alg_P of algebras over P in C locally presentable?

It seems that one can relatively easy establish the accessibility of algebras over P using [PIE-limits](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/PIE-limit).

However, the forgetful functor Alg_P→C preserves neither limits nor colimits, so it’s unclear how one could establish the (co)completeness of Alg_P.

An example of the category of algebras over a prop
that is known to be locally presentable
is given by [Hopf monoids](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hopf+monoid).
As shown in §4.1.3 of Horst's paper “Universal constructions for Hopf algebras” [doi:10.1016/j.jpaa.2008.04.007](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2008.04.007),
under certain additional conditions on C
the category of Hopf monoids in C is locally presentable.
The proof exploits the special structure of the Hopf monoid prop.

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question (and it is one I have wondered).  I've always understood Horst's result as depending on the "factorization" or "distributivity" of the Bialgebra prop into a composition of Algebra and Coalgebra.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd: Yes, Horst proceeds from monoids to bimonoids to Hopf monoids, which is very specific to the Hopf monoid prop.

Comment: It looks like unital-counital Frobenius algebras in Vect have neither an initial nor a terminal object.